# Nomenclatura-How to display one symbol used in two differents contexts or more

Tags: nomenclature

The following example builds one nomenclatura (the list of some importa symbols).

The problem I met is the following one : if one symbol is used in two contexts, this symbol appears two times (see the letter a in my example).

Is it possible to change this so as to obtain for example the letter a appears only one time in the nomenclatura following by list of the different uses of this letter ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{nomencl}
    \makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
    a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%

\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel} follows easily.

Let's try with another $a$... %
\nomenclature{$a$}{The area of the needle point}%

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The solution given just after by Werner does the job but there is still one problem from my point of view.

Instead of...

```
a    The number of angels per unit area
     The area of the needle point
```

it would be better to have something like...

```
a    - The number of angels per unit area
     - The area of the needle point
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following example I played around with the sort order of `nomencl` by using the `<prefix>` command:

```
\nomencl[<prefix>]{<symbol>}{<description>}
```

However, it required to transform all the nomenclatures to the same type (string in this case). That is, using the prefix for each item (in text/non-math) so that they are sorted in the same group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
    a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature[a]{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature[N]{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature[A]{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%

\nomenclature[s]{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature[m]{$m$}{The mass of one angel} follows easily.

Let's try with another $a$... %
\nomenclature[a1]{}{The area of the needle point}%
\nomenclature[a2]{}{The distance to the moon}%
\nomenclature[a3]{}{The number of needles in a haystack}%
\nomenclature[a4]{}{The value of $pi$}%
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image: Nomenclature with prefix-sorted list]

In the above example, all items under the `a` nomenclature that should be printed *without* `a`, has been given a prefix `a?` where `?` is a numeric to force some sort order.

Text-only nomenclatures can be used in the traditional form without the prefix `<prefix>`, like (say) `\nomenclature{C}{This is a C, see.}`; included in the above MWE. You'll notice that the `\sigma` entry has been sorted based on the text prefix `s`. This can be changed if needed.

Since there is no connection between the items in the List of Nomenclatures and the grouped sorting has been manually altered (via specifying `a1`, `a2`, ... for items using the same symbol as `a`), there is no way to easily accommodate the following request automatically:

[image: Nomenclature with a manual indication of similarly marked items]

Manually, however, it is no problem. Just add the respective dashed (`--` or en-dash) before each item. This should not be a major drawback, since the nomenclature items are formatted and inserted manually in the document anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section*{Main equations}

\begin{equation}
    a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature[a]{$a$}{--\ The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature[N]{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature[A]{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%

The equation $\sigma = m a$%

\nomenclature[s]{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature[m]{$m$}{The mass of one angel} follows easily.

Let's try with another $a$... %
\nomenclature[a1]{}{--\ The area of the needle point}%
\nomenclature[a2]{}{--\ The distance to the moon}%
\nomenclature[a3]{}{--\ The number of needles in a haystack}%
\nomenclature[a4]{}{--\ The value of $pi$}%

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Is there a way to have display some symbol before each item of the list ?

Comment: @projetmbc: I thought you were interested in *removing* the symbol before each item in the duplicated symbol. Do you want some symbol printed before *each* item in the list? Please provide more detail; perhaps even by editing your original question to include this information.

Comment: I've edited my first message so as to point what I'm looking for.

Comment: @projetmbc: See my revised answer. Hope this helps.